# how many arrays satisfy the property (*)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

An array $A = (A [0], \dots, A [n-1])$ of length $n$ satisfies the following property $(*)$.

$(*)$ For all $i$, $A[i]$ is equal to the number of times $i$ occurs in array $A$.

For example, when $n = 5,$ $(2,1,2,0,0) $ is an array that satisfies this property $(*)$. If $n = 6$, how many arrays satisfy the property $(*)$?

Comment: These are related to the autobiographical numbers http://oeis.org/A046043

Comment: ? you are saying there must be $n$ occurrences of the number $n$ in the array. So 2,1,2,0,0 ? It has indeed got two 2s and one 1, but it has not got zero 0s.

Comment: @almagest The mathematical definition didn't match the rest of the description. I have changed it, hopefully to the correct one.

Comment: It is fairly easy to show that there aren't any such arrays for $n=6$.

Comment: But this all seems like a programming exercise rather than math. One can produce ad hoc arguments for small $n$, but to get exact answers for large $n$, I can't see how to do it except by running an algorithm on a computer.

Comment: How did you show that there aren't any such array for n=6?